# Visual Studio Extensibility: Move to line in a TextDocument

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am in the focus of a ToolWindow. By doing dobleclick on a TreeView node, the cursor has to move to a particular line within the opened source code document. I solved this issue by calling the Edit.GoTo Line command like this:

```
var commandName = "Edit.GoTo " + lineNumber;
_dte.ExecuteCommand(commandName);
```

However I am not quite convinient with that as I lose the focus of the toolwindow. Is there another way to move to a line by using the Automation API?

Comment: Could you switch the focus back to the tool window after your command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`IViewScroller.EnsureSpanVisible(SnapshotSpan span, EnsureSpanVisibleOptions options)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iviewscroller.ensurespanvisible)

To create a span, use:

```
var lines = view.VisualSnapshot.Lines;

var startLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(a => a.LineNumber == fromLine - 1);
var endLine = lines.FirstOrDefault(a => a.LineNumber == toLine - 1);

if (startLine == null || endLine == null)
    return;

var startPosition = startLine.Start;
var endPosition = endLine.Start;

var span = new SnapshotSpan(view.TextSnapshot, Span.FromBounds(startPosition, endPosition));
```

And to scroll to the span:

```
layer.TextView.ViewScroller.EnsureSpanVisible(span,
    EnsureSpanVisibleOptions.AlwaysCenter);
```

Where `view` is the `IWpfTextView` provided by your adorner (`IWpfTextViewCreationListener`)